# Autofac Generic factories

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, autofac

I develop web application and my data access is using Entity framework 6 code first

I have those dependencies in my DataService layer:

```
public DataService(IRepository<Folder> folders, IRepository<Letter> letters, IRepository<Destination> destinations)
```

Into those depebdencies I inject the following types seperately:

FoldersRepository,

LettersRepository,

DestinationsRepository

I need those repositories with per request liftime. Is there any way to inject them with Autofac in a better than one by one (for a case I'll add more repositories and the future)

I don't want reference from my DAL to Autofac.

EDIT: This is what I want to have :

```
public IRepository<T> where T: BaseEntityObject
{
    void Add(T entity);

    void Remove(T entity);

    List<T> Get();

    T FindById(int id);

    int SaveChanges();

    void Dispose();

}


public abstract class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;

    public EFRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public abstract List<T> Get();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Add(item);
    }

    public void Remove(T item)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Remove(item);
    }

    public void Update(T item)
    {
        Context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Context.Dispose();
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public T FindById(int id)
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().Find(id); 
    }
}


public LettersRepository : EFRepository<Letter>
{
    public LettersRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) {}

    // Override for case includes will be needed in future
    public override List<T> Get()
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().ToList();
    }
}

public FoldersRepository : EFRepository<Folder>
{
    public FoldersRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) {}

    public override List<T> Get()
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().Include("Letters").ToList();
    }
}


public class DataService
{
    private IRepositoriesFactory _repositoriesFactory;

    public DataService(IRepositoriesFactory repositoriesFactory)
    {
        _repositoriesFactory = repositoriesFactory;
    }

    public bool AddFolder(Folder folder)
    {
        var isAdded = false;

        using (var foldersRepository = _repositoriesFactory.Create<FoldersRepository>)
        {
            if (foldersRepository.Add(folder))
            {
                foldersRepository.SaveChanges();
                isAdded = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Log("folder couldn't be addded");
            }
        }

        return isAdded;
    }
}

    public bool AddLetter(Letter letter)
    {
        var isAdded = false;

        using (var lettersRepository = _repositoriesFactory.Create<LettersRepository>)
        {
            if (lettersRepositoryv.Add(folder))
            {
                lettersRepository.SaveChanges();
                isAdded = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Log("letter couldn't be addded");
            }
        }

        return isAdded;
    }

    // More methods that manipulates data...
}

// This layer is not in my DAL project (the one using EF), Data service is the API supplier for DAL
public class DataAccessLayer
{
    private IDataService _dataService

    public DataAccessLayer(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService
    }

    public void HandleAddFolderRequest(AddFolderRequestMessage msg)
    {
        if (!_dataService.AddFolder(msg.Folder))
        {
            Log ("Adding folder failed");
            Broadcast(new AddFolderResponseMessage());
            return;
        }

        Log("Adding folder succeeded");
        Broadcast(new AddFolderResponseMessage(true));      
    }

    public void HandleAddLetterRequest(AddLetterRequestMessage msg)
    {
        if (!_dataService.AddLetter(msg.letter))
        {
            Log ("Adding letter failed");
            Broadcast(new AddLetterResponseMessage());
            return;
        }

        Log("Adding letter succeeded");
        Broadcast(new AddLetterResponseMessage(true));      
    }

    public void HandleGetAllFolderLetters(GetFolderRequestMessage msg)
    {
        var letters = _dataService.GetFolderLetters(msg.FolderId);

        if (letters == null)
        {
            Log ("Could not get the folder's letters");
            Broadcast(new GetFolderResponseMessage());
            return;
        }

        Log("Got the folder's letters successfull");
        Broadcast(new GetFolderResponseMessage(true));      
    }

    // And so on.. more data manipulatation handling methods
}


// The Part I dont know how and where to implement

public interface IRepositoriesFactory
{
    T Create<T>() where T : class 
}

public class RepositoriesFactory : IRepositoriesFactory
{
    public T Create<T>() where T : class
    {
        // THE MAGIC HAPPENS HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,  I think quote "what are the pros/cons of using Autofac in an xml configuratuon instead of code based??" should be a separate question perhaps.

Comment: Back to your original question... I think its hard to tell without more context... code. I am used to seeing the injection in the controller... but not at the service level.. I don't believe there would be a way. They would need to be injected one by one... by saying that... are you not giving one service* to much responsibility... and would rather focus on that as a root for concern.

Comment: Agreed about the configuration. I Edited and put most of the code, hope you or anyone could help

Comment: the code you submitted does not highlight or show best practice when it come to ioc and dependency injection. I may have not worded that correctly for what i mean. what i mean is... why are you creating an instance of your repo like that... please show code where you are passing in multiple repos so i may analyse that.... where it is applicable to the discussion at hand..

Comment: I take that factory in my ctor like that because I want to create repositories per request. In some transactions it might take more than 1 repository I believe. In my upper layer I just instaniate the DataService and use the functions..

Comment: To much code which isn't making much sense to me. Create service class. eg. UserService.... this class is responsible for everything to do with a User... you may need access to the connected Repositories... so you inject them in. IRepository<Folder> folders, IRepository<Letter> letters, IRepository<Destination> destinations. Then if you have another area of isolation* then you create a service class for that. As i don't know your app i cant give a good dummy example.It may help if I could just post code... as it would be easier to understand...?

Comment: I added the code the actually access my DAL - access my DataService.
This is actually all the code I have right now that has to do with my DAL.
I only got the repositories, my application context and DataService which should be injected with repositories.
Do you suggest to create Services such as DataService for each area? That way I wouldn't need all my repositories in one class, and just inject all of these services to my DataAccessLayer?

Comment: Hey sozs, FYI i mean i should post code not you... ;-)

Comment: Oh sorry!! Yeah code could always help, but regardless, you gave me the thought I should split my DataService into few smaller services that will take only repoaitories related to them, is that what you meant in your previous answer?

Comment: yes... smaller service class each with there own responsibilities... like access stuff or user data or whatever.

Comment: I understand! By the way you didn't say anything about the way I save the context. I do it at the end of each data service in case there was no execption thrown. Is that good practice?

Comment: hey sorry man, did you see my answer post.. ill add to that... PS probably didnt say anything cozs i dont like it all...;-) trying to get you away from creating instances which should already exist...Ill add and update to my answer thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just to serve as an illustration and may not be connected to answering the question.

Assuming this is a MVC web Project:

You would have a Controller.

E.g HomeController

Lets say that the HomeContoller was responsible for a dashboard and showed you all sorts of juicy information.

So we need data....

```
class HomeContoller
{
     ServiceClass1  _serviceClass1
     public HomeContoller(ServiceClass1  serviceClass1)
     {
         _serviceClass1 = serviceClass1;
     }

     public ActionResult Index()
     { 
         var data = _serviceClass1.GetFancyData();
         return View(data);
     }


}
```

That is the basics you can make this more or less complicated... ie like you your case you want to do this at your service layer. At this point i have no idea if that is a good idea or not.... but reading someone else comment i dont think it is.

Anyway the point here is im trying to show you that is makes no sense to construct and instance using DI type code in your DataService.

I will expand on this as the questions follow.

**Update** Example!!!

```
public class FolderService
{
    private IFoldersRepository _foldersRepository;

    public FolderService(IFoldersRepository foldersRepository)
    {
        _foldersRepository = foldersRepository;
    }

    public bool SaveFolder(Folder folder)
    {
        if (folder == null)
            return false;

        if (folder.Id == 0)
        {
            folder.CreateOnDate = DateTime.Now;
            _foldersRepository.Folders.Add(folder);
        }

        //change this to cast the SaveChanges to bool
        // also not so sure this is a gd idea... bt thats by the by for this....
        //---------------------
        try 
        {
            _foldersRepository.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch(exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        //---------------------
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks alot! Regarding your update, I didn't understand the diffrrenece between the context saving in your code and what I posted, am I wrong? Where is the Context coming from? The context is saved inside the epository

Comment: Sorry you are 100% correct i didn't finish my example..... haha totally right where the hell did "Conetxt" come from... but i think you get it now this would be from _foldersRepository... Ill update to reflect correctly. But again lots of code is kinda missing i was just trying to show.. how it would kinda look. Corrected stuff,  let me know if there are more mistakes sozs copied this from one of my own project and seemed to have missed change a few things

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should just install autofac to your **driver project**(top) and you should register your classes there. All of other projects should use interfaces.

Then you can use generic registration.

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```